# Saving contacts when I change ROM on Xiaomi MI3

Tags: contacts, recovery-mode, twrp, xiaomi, miui

I have a Xiaomi MI3 running an Android 6.0 CyanogenMod version. I want to return to use a MIUI Rom, but I don't know how save all the contacts (a lot of them aren't saved on the google account, they are saved on the phone).

What I have to do to save all the contacts (in order to have them when I'll install the MIUI Rom)?

Usually, I use TeamWin TWRP Recovery to install Roms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just about contacts, that should be easy:

1. open the contacts app
2. tap the "overflow menu" (the 3 "stapled dots", usually in the upper-right corner)
3. select *Export/Import*
4. select *Export to SD card* (might be named slightly different)

A few seconds later, there should be a file called `0001.vcf` in the root of your SD card. That's all your contacts stored in VCard format. Copy that file to your PC (or any other safe place off the device). If later you wish to restore them again, the same procedure can be used – except that in step 4 you'd need to chose "Import from SD card", of course.